# How to access local resource : MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, resources

I cam across [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1655383.aspx/1) thread that ask how to access local resource and he solved his own problem but my situation is a little bit different.

```
Areas>Models>Support>Localization
                             MyResouces.resx
                     SupportModel
```

Inside my SupportModel I want to access values from Localization/MyResouces.resx. What is the syntax?

One solution is to use HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObjec(virtual path, key) but it has not worked for me. I have used

```
GetLocalResourceObject("~/Areas/Models/Support/SupportModel", "option1Text")
```

I also renamed the Localization folder to App_LocalResources but that did not solve the problem. May I am doing something wrong?

Note that I have modified my code as I did not want to post the real code. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used is this. Interesting there is no solution available online.

```
using Myproject.Areas.Models.Support.Localization;
...
MyResouces.option1
```

The above is not actually compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

To access values from Localization/MyResouces.resx, try this:

```
@Areas.Models.Support.Localization.MyResouces.option1Text
```

syntax: *[namespace].[ResourceName].[Property]*

provided that your MyResouces.resx file has `public` access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example application with Resource1.resx file inside Models/Support that's how I get the values from it:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var res = Models.Support.Resource1.TestString1;  // this is resource created inside Models/Support/
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it in the view using the following syntax:

```
@Resources.IndexPage.PropertyName
```

And you have to make sure your resource file has the following properties:
Build Action: Embedded Resource
Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace: Resources.IndexPage (This is a namespace given by you, it is used in the view to access properties.

Have a look at this article:
http://www.chambaud.com/2013/02/27/localization-in-asp-net-mvc-4/